# Should updating an element in List<T> by index be quicker than using ArrayList index?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I am running through some tests about using ArrayLists and List.

Speed is very important in my app.

I have tested creating 10000 records in each, finding an item by index and then updating that object for example:

```
List[i] = newX;
```

Using the arraylist seems much faster. Is that correct?

**UPDATE:**

Using the List[i] approach, for my `List<T>` approach I am using LINQ to find the index eg/

....

```
int index = base.FindIndex(x=>x.AlpaNumericString = "PopItem");
base[index] = UpdatedItem;
```

It is definately slower than

```
ArrayList.IndexOf("PopItem"))
base[index] = UpdatedItem;
```

Comment: List<T> has an IndexOf method as well. How does that perform?

Comment: @Jon: Regarding your edit, it looks as though you're trying to compare apples and oranges. The items in your `List<T>` seem to be a custom type and you're testing a particular property of that type to find your index. The items in your `ArrayList` appear to just be strings and you're performing a straight equality comparison to find your index. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your recent edit it seems as though you're not performing a 1:1 comparison here. In the List you have a class object and you're looking for the index based on a property, whereas in the ArrayList you just store the values of that property. If so, this is a severely flawed comparison.

To make it a 1:1 comparison you would add the values to the list only, not the class. Or, you would add the class items to the ArrayList. The former would allow you to use `IndexOf` on both collections. The latter would entail looping through your entire ArrayList and comparing each item till a match was found (and you could do the same for the List), or overriding object.Equals since ArrayList uses that for comparison.

For an interesting read, I suggest taking a look at Rico Mariani's post: [Performance Quiz #7 -- Generics Improvements and Costs -- Solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2005/08/26/performance-quiz-7-generics-improvements-and-costs-solution.aspx). Even in that post Rico also emphasizes the need to benchmark different scenarios. No blanket statement is issued about ArrayLists, although the general consensus is to use generic lists for performance, type safety, and having a strongly typed collection.

Another related article is: [Why should I use List and not ArrayList](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dhelper/archive/2008/10/10/why-does-list-lt-t-gt-is-better-then-arraylist.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

A generic List (`List<T>`) should always be quicker than an ArrayList.

Firstly, an `ArrayList` is not strongly-typed and accepts types of `object`, so if you're storing value types in the `ArrayList`, they are going to be [boxed and unboxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28VS.80%29.aspx) every time they are added or accessed.

A Generic List can be defined to accept only (say) `int`'s so therefore no boxing or unboxing needs to occur when adding/accessing elements of the list.

If you're dealing with reference types, you're probably still better off with a Generic List over an ArrayList, since although there's no boxing/unboxing going on, your Generic List is type-safe, and there will be no implicit (or explicit) casts required when retrieving your strongly-typed object from the ArrayList's "collection" of `object` types.

There may be some edge-cases where an ArrayList is faster performing than a Generic List, however, I (personally) have not yet come across one.  Even the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) states:

> **Performance Considerations**
>
> In deciding whether to use the
>   List<(Of <(T>)>) or ArrayList class,
>   both of which have similar
>   functionality, remember that the
>   List<(Of <(T>)>) class performs better
>   in most cases and is type safe. If a
>   reference type is used for type T of
>   the List<(Of <(T>)>) class, the
>   behavior of the two classes is
>   identical. However, if a value type is
>   used for type T, you need to consider
>   implementation and boxing issues.
>
> If a value type is used for type T,
>   the compiler generates an
>   implementation of the List<(Of <(T>)>)
>   class specifically for that value
>   type. That means a list element of a
>   List<(Of <(T>)>) object does not have
>   to be boxed before the element can be
>   used, and after about 500 list
>   elements are created the memory saved
>   not boxing list elements is greater
>   than the memory used to generate the
>   class implementation.
>
> Make certain the value type used for
>   type T implements the IEquatable<(Of
>   <(T>)>) generic interface. If not,
>   methods such as Contains must call the
>   Object..::.Equals(Object) method,
>   which boxes the affected list element.
>   If the value type implements the
>   IComparable interface and you own the
>   source code, also implement the
>   IComparable<(Of <(T>)>) generic
>   interface to prevent the BinarySearch
>   and Sort methods from boxing list
>   elements. If you do not own the source
>   code, pass an IComparer<(Of <(T>)>)
>   object to the BinarySearch and Sort
>   methods

Moreover, I particularly like the very last section of that paragraph, which states:

> It is to your advantage to use the type-specific implementation of the List<(Of <(T>)>) class instead of using the ArrayList class or writing a strongly typed wrapper collection yourself. **The reason is your implementation must do what the .NET Framework does for you already, and the common language runtime can share Microsoft intermediate language code and metadata, which your implementation cannot.**

Touché!   :)

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList seems faster?  According to the documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx ) List should be faster when using a value type, and the same speed when using a reference type.  ArrayList is slower with value types because it needs to box/unbox the values when you're accessing them.

Comment: My <T> is a class with properties for example a CDCollection of CD

List<CD>....
Cd.Artist
CD.Genre

Answer (score 1):

I would expect them to be about the same if they are value-types. There is an extra cast/type-check for `ArrayList`, but nothing huge. Of course, `List<T>` should be *preferred*. If speed is the primary concern (which it almost always isn't, at least not in this way), then you might also want to profile an array (`T[]`) - harder (=more expensive) to add/remove, of course - but if you are just querying/assigning by index, it should be the fastest. I have had to resort to arrays for some **very localised** performance critical work, but 99.95% of the time this is overkill and should be avoided.

For example, for *any* of the 3 approaches (`List<T>`/`ArrayList`/`T[]`) I would expect the assignment cost to be insignificant to the cost of `new`ing up the new instance to put *into* the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Marc Gravell touched on this in his anwswer - I think it needs to be stressed.

**It is usually a waste of time to prematurely optimize your code!**

A better approach is to do a simple, well designed first implementation, and test it with anticipated real world data loads.

Often, you will find that it's "fast enough". (It helps to start out with a clear definition of "fast enough" - e.g. "Must be able to find a single CD in a 10,000 CD collection in 3 seconds or less")

If it's not, put a profiler on it.  Almost invariably, the bottle neck will NOT be where you expect.

(I learned this the hard way when I brought a whole app to it's knees with single badly chosen string concatenation)

Comment: Using the LINQ approach took 2 minutes.  IndexOf took 2 seconds! I want to use LINQ but not that badly

Comment: I agree - that's a pretty severe penalty!  I like LINQ too, but have not done enough with it yet to understand why your code would run so slow.